# Best way to return False for list of empty tuples

Tags: python, list, boolean

Sometimes, DB returns list of empty tuples as such `[(), (), ()]`. I need to set `False` for this type of return. Here is what I do:

Say:

```
a = [(), (), ()]
b = all([bool(i) for i in a])
print b
False
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What you do is wrong. When you use `all`, you get `False` if even just one of the tuples is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you want to use `any`, not `all`:

```
>>> a = [(), (), ()]
>>> b = all(a)
>>> print b
False
>>>

>>> a = [(), (1,), ()]
>>> b = all(a)
>>> print b
False
>>>

>>> a = [(), (), ()]
>>> b = any(a)
>>> print b
False
>>>

>>> a = [(), (1,), ()]
>>> b = any(a)
>>> print b
True
>>>
```

Notice that `all` will return `False` unless **every element** is "truthy".

You don't need to use `bool` at all.

Answer (score 5):

Use `any()` to check if any are non-empty.

```
any([(), (), ()])
```

Comment: I need to return False, only if all tuples are empty but tx.

Comment: @dt1369: You may want to test this for yourself then.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you. I should have tested